# how to change Narration from direct to indirect

Tags: narration

The young girl said," if fashion do not change, many manufactures will have to sit idle."

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: The original should read "if fashion *does* not change..."   and that would become "The girl said that if fashion *didn't* change, many manufacturers *would* have to sit idle."

Comment: @TRomano: argument rages on this site about the subjunctive, but you really can't just dismiss it without any explanation.

Comment: @TimLymington: I'm not dismissing the subjunctive, just this particular instance. I use the subjunctive more than many do. *If it do not* is downright antiquated (or a vestigial survival in a regional dialect). https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=(if+it+do+not)&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28if%20it%20do%20not%29%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 2):

If the situation reported is still valid at the time of reporting, then this is possible "The girl said (that) if fashion doesn't change, many manufacturers will sit idle".

Whether or not the situation is still valid, backshifting is correct: "The girl said (that) if fashion didn't change, many manufacturers would sit idle". If the situation is no longer valid at the moment of reporting, backshifting is obligatory.